# ¿Cómo podría hacer una consulta de Angular a Firestore con dos condiciones?

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Me gustaría saber si se podría realizar una consulta a la base de datos de Firestore desde Angular y que compruebe dos valores.

La consulta que quiero realizar en Angular es la siguiente, pero en MySQL:

```
SELECT * FROM films WHERE userUid == "id" OR compartir_con == "id"
```

Para hacer esa consulta ahora mismo tengo dos funciones:

```
getAllYourFilms(id) {
    this.filmsCollection = this.afs.collection('films', ref => ref.where('userUid', '==', id));
    return this.films = this.filmsCollection.snapshotChanges()
      .pipe(map(changes => {
        return changes.map(action => {
          const data = action.payload.doc.data() as FilmInterface;
          data.id = action.payload.doc.id;
          return data;
        });
      }));
  }

getAllFilmsSharedWithYou(email) {
    this.filmsCollection = this.afs.collection('films', ref => ref.where('compartir_con', '==', email));
    return this.films = this.filmsCollection.snapshotChanges()
      .pipe(map(changes => {
        return changes.map(action => {
          const data = action.payload.doc.data() as FilmInterface;
          data.id = action.payload.doc.id;
          return data;
        });
      }));
  }
```

Pues eso, únicamente me gustaría saber si se puede realizar un `OR` en la consulta para después paginar los resultados y no recoger, en el caso de tener 10000 resultados, pues los 10000 a la vez, cargaría muy lento.

La idea sería por ejemplo ir mostrando los resultados de 10 en 10 y que no los recogiera todos a la vez de la base de datos.

Actualmente con dos funciones recojo los valores que devuelven esas dos funciones y uno los resultados con una concatenación, pero así recoge todos los valores. Y si recogiera 5 y 5 y luego los uno no sirve, ya que están ordenados alfabéticamente.

Otra opción sería crear dentro de la película un **Array** que tenga a todos los usuarios con acceso a la película, después se recogerían los valores con `ref.where("acceso_usuarios", "array-contains", "id")`, pero estoy empezando en Angular y tengo que ver como crear un Array para guardarlo en la base de datos y tal.

Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Ale, ya lo arreglé, dejo la solución por si a alguien le pasara, es que piensas en Angular como si fuera algo raro... pero en verdad es Javascript.

Al crear la película en el momento de recoger los datos le añado este valor a un campo oculto del formulario:

```
var usuariosconpermiso = [this.userUid];
var compartidocon = serieForm.value.compartir_con.split(/\s*,\s*/);
usuariosconpermiso = usuariosconpermiso.concat(compartidocon);
```

Así puedo buscar directamente si el id de usuario existe en esa película y no necesito ningún **OR** en la consulta.